# SSIS package fails in SQL server Agent

Tags: python, sql-server, ssis

I have python script to copy data from excel to CSV file. I have created Execute Process Task package in SSIS and deployed to SSISDB. This works fine when i execute in SSIS and in SSISDB manually.However,if i schedule or execute through SQL server agent it fails. I am using proxy account to schedule package. Other "**non python SSIS package**" runs fine in sql server agent.

**Error -**

> Execute PY Script:Error: In Executing C:\Program
> Files\Python311\python.exe"  "\\org\data\project\test.py" at
> "\\org\data\project", The process exit code was "1" while the
> expected was "0".

**Python Script -**

```
print('Start CSV File Conversion') 
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame, read_csv
file = r'\\\org\data\project\test.xlsm'
dframe = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name='data')
export_csv = dframe.to_csv( R'\\\org\data\project\test.csv', index=None, header=True, sep='~')
print(dframe)
print('...Completed')
```

All Files are saved in **\\org\data\project**

I am learning pyhton. Any inputs will be helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you set the Proxy Account Properties accordingly? `SQL Server => SQL Server Agent => Proxies => Operating System (CmdExec)`

Comment: yes, i have done. SQL Server => SQL Server Agent => Proxies => chekced on subsystem  Operating System (CmdExec) and SQL Server integration services package

Answer (score 0):

that doesn't look like ssis related error but python error. Check your code, may be create VS project where you can test it to escape complexity of running through SSIS.

Comment: I tried running in visual stuio and i get warning, though it completes the run.

Warning - This version of python seems to be incorrectly compiled
(internal generated filenames are not absolute).
This may make the debugger miss breakpoints.
Related bug: http://bugs.python.org/issue1666807

I executed in visual studio code, it was fine. Not if it has to do with permission or something else.

Comment: if you create sql job to run it you can set up a user (as for example administrator) and that wy it will run with another user and you will escape the permission issue. You only need to find which user will have permissions.